# Realmente é necessário criar uma propriedade que indica a foreign-key de uma relação One-To-Many?

Tags: entity-framework

Gostaria de saber se as informações que encontrei após buscas, que resumidamente, está no link abaixo, procede:

http://www.tiselvagem.com.br/desenvolvimento/chave-estrangeira-e-associacao-independente-no-entity-framework/

**Pergunta:**

Em uma situação hipotética, se temos a classe *Carro* e a classe *Marca*, onde *Carro* tem uma *Marca* e *Marca* pode ter vários *Carros* (One-to-Many), o *EntityFramework* me obriga a criar um campo 'MarcaId' no objeto *Carro*, ou caso contrário, eu teria que carregar todo o objeto *Marca* no momento de uma inclusão/alteração de um *Carro* **se eu não quiser utilizar um campo** *MarcaId* ?

**Motivo da pergunta:**

Inclusive nos links em que encontrei esta informação, frizam que esta prática fere as boas práticas da OO. Existe uma solução melhor para estes casos?

Answer (score 1):

### o EntityFramework me obriga a criar um campo `MarcaId` no objeto Carro?

Sim. É o padrão do Framework.

Adicionalmente, você teria que adicionar uma propriedade de navegação (como abaixo) para ficar inteiramente dentro do padrão:

```
public virtual Marca Marca { get; set; }
```

### eu teria que carregar todo o objeto `Marca` no momento de uma inclusão/alteração de um `Carro`?

Não. A carga de `Marca` é preguiçosa por padrão. É feita na propriedade de navegação que mencionei acima.

Não concordo que o padrão do Entity Framework fere práticas de OO.

## ...se eu não quiser utilizar um campo `MarcaId`?

Se você não quiser usar, não vai funcionar, simplesmente, porque você não está seguindo o padrão do Framework. `MarcaId` é mapeada em banco, portanto precisa existir como propriedade na classe `Carro`.

## Sobre o tutorial

Ele tem várias imprecisões. Não recomendo se basear por ele.

Comment: Editei o trecho sobre a pergunta _eu teria que carregar todo o objeto Marca no momento de uma inclusão/alteração de um Carro?_ , não especifiquei a situação.

Comment: @JoaquimMagalhães Editei a resposta.

Comment: Pessoalmente acho muito estranho! Se já configurei a chave do objeto Marca, por que o EF me obriga a criar um campo `MarcaId` ao invés de utilizar `Marca.Id`. Estou alterando o modelo (uma representação de um conceito do mundo real) com a finalidade de atender ao framework de persistência. Obrigado pelos eslcarecimentos e desculpe-me pelas insistências... rs

Comment: @JoaquimMagalhães Porque um *Model* reflete a representação de dados do banco de dados. Se por exemplo você tem uma `DropDownList` em uma tela de edição e ela está baseada em `MarcaId` (supondo, hipoteticamente, que você pode trocar a marca do carro), não faz sentido usar `Marca.Id`. Você estaria alterando um dado de `Carro`, e não de `Marca`.

Comment: Entendo. Está mais relacionado a um _Model_ do que um _Dominio do problema_. Nesta visão faz sentido!

Comment: MVC  com Entity Framework não é DDD estrito. Ele segue algumas coisas do DDD, tanto que podemos dizer que ele implementa o DDD, mas de uma forma mais flexível.